# collapsing whitespace in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that kind of looks like this:

```
"stuff   .  // : /// more-stuff .. .. ...$%$% stuff -> DD"
```

and I want to strip off all punctuation, make everything uppercase and collapse all whitespace so that it looks like this:

```
"STUFF MORE STUFF STUFF DD"
```

Is this possible with one regex or do I need to combine more than two? This is what I have so far:

```
def normalize(string):
    import re

    string = string.upper()

    rex   = re.compile(r'\W')
    rex_s = re.compile(r'\s{2,}')

    result = rex.sub(' ', string) # this produces a string with tons of whitespace padding
    result = rex.sub('', result) # this reduces all those spaces

    return result
```

The only thing that doesn't work is the whitespace collapsing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a single-step approach (but the uppercasing actually uses a string method -- much simpler!):

```
rex = re.compile(r'\W+')
result = rex.sub(' ', strarg).upper()
```

where `strarg` is the string argument (*don't* use names that shadow builtins or standard library modules, *please*).

Comment: I agree that this would definitely be the simpler way to approach the problem.

Comment: I assume that should be "string" and not "result" in the argument of rex.sub?  Or is this only replacing part of the user's code?

Comment: @Brooks, you're right -- I'm SO averse to shadowing builtin and standard module names, that anything BUT string flew off my fingertips. Let me edit to fix, and thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
s = "$$$aa1bb2 cc-dd ee_ff ggg."
re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', s).upper()
# ' AA1BB2 CC DD EE_FF GGG '
```

Is _ punctuation?

```
re.sub(r'[_\W]+', ' ', s).upper()
# ' AA1BB2 CC DD EE FF GGG '
```

Don't want the leading and trailing space?

```
re.sub(r'[_\W]+', ' ', s).strip().upper()
# 'AA1BB2 CC DD EE FF GGG'
```

Comment: +1 For bypassing the `re.compile(...)` step. If I could, I'd give you another +1 for also pointing out the question of how to handle '_' and leading/trailing WS, as these things are so often overlooked with regex.

Answer (score 3):

```
result = rex.sub(' ', string) # this produces a string with tons of whitespace padding
result = rex.sub('', result) # this reduces all those spaces
```

Because you typo'd and forgot to use rex_s for the second call instead. Also, you need to substitute at least one space back in or you'll end up with any multiple-space gap becoming no gap at all, instead of a single-space gap.

```
result = rex.sub(' ', string) # this produces a string with tons of whitespace padding
result = rex_s.sub(' ', result) # this reduces all those spaces
```

Comment: good catch on the type part. I just noticed that moments after posting. you beat me before I got the chance to edit OMG

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at Alex's code - it's a lot more concise way of approaching the problem, and it also handles punctuation/whitespace at the end of the string nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use regular expressions?  Do you feel you must do it in one line?

```
>>> import string
>>> s = "stuff   .  // : /// more-stuff .. .. ...$%$% stuff -> DD"
>>> s2 = ''.join(c for c in s if c in string.letters + ' ')
>>> ' '.join(s2.split())
'stuff morestuff stuff DD'
```

Answer (score 0):

works in python3 this will retain the same whitespace character you collapsed. So if you have a tab and a space next to each other they wont collapse into a single character.

```
def collapse_whitespace_characters(raw_text):
    ret = ''
    if len(raw_text) > 1:
        prev_char = raw_text[0]
        ret += prev_char
        for cur_char in raw_text[1:]:
            if not cur_char.isspace() or cur_char != prev_char:
                ret += cur_char
            prev_char = cur_char
    else:
        ret = raw_text
    return ret
```

this one will collapse whitespace sets into the first whitespace character it sees

```
def collapse_whitespace(raw_text):
    ret = ''
    if len(raw_text) > 1:
        prev_char = raw_text[0]
        ret += prev_char
        for cur_char in raw_text[1:]:
            if not cur_char.isspace() or \
                    (cur_char.isspace() and not prev_char.isspace()):
                ret += cur_char
            prev_char = cur_char
    else:
        ret = raw_text
    return ret
```

>>> collapse_whitespace_characters('we like    spaces  and\t\t TABS   AND WHATEVER\xa0\xa0IS')
'we like spaces and\t TABS\tAND WHATEVER\xa0IS'

>>> collapse_whitespace('we like    spaces  and\t\t TABS   AND WHATEVER\xa0\xa0IS')

'we like spaces and\tTABS\tAND WHATEVER\xa0IS'

for punctuation

```
def collapse_punctuation(raw_text):
    ret = ''
    if len(raw_text) > 1:
        prev_char = raw_text[0]
        ret += prev_char
        for cur_char in raw_text[1:]:
            if cur_char.isalnum() or cur_char != prev_char:
                ret += cur_char
            prev_char = cur_char
    else:
        ret = raw_text
    return ret
```

to actually answer the question

```
orig = 'stuff   .  // : /// more-stuff .. .. ...$%$% stuff -> DD'
collapse_whitespace(''.join([(c.upper() if c.isalnum() else ' ') for c in orig]))
```

as said, the regexp would be something like

```
re.sub('\W+', ' ', orig).upper()
```

Comment: while correct, this is a VERY INEFFICIENT way to do it. This will be copying strings over and over just to append one additional character each time.

Answer (score 0):

One can use regular expression to substitute reoccurring white spaces. 
White space is given by `\s` with `\s+` meaning: at least one.

```
import re
rex = re.compile(r'\s+')
test = "     x  y z           z"
res = rex.sub(' ', test)
print(f">{res}<")
```

## > x y z z<

Note this also affects/includes carriage return, etc.